# Extracting number from file name with boost::filesystem and boost::lexical_cast

Tags: c++, boost

Please help.
I have a file with name:

> X_ab_LOTA123.png

Then I have this code and I am able to extract the number 123 from the file name. Everything works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;
namespace ba = boost::adaptors;
using std::string;
using namespace std;

void find(const bfs::path& imageDirPath, const boost::regex& filter)
{
   boost::smatch result;
   for (auto& entry : boost::make_iterator_range(bfs::directory_iterator(imageDirPath), {})
         | ba::filtered(static_cast<bool (*)(const bfs::path &)>(&bfs::is_regular_file))
         | ba::filtered([&](const bfs::path &path){ return boost::regex_match(path.filename().string(), result, filter); })
       )
   {
     int32_t num = boost::lexical_cast<int32_t>(result[1]);
     cout << "found : " << num << " = " << entry.path().string() << endl;
   }
}

int main()
{
   const boost::regex defaultFilter( "X_ab_LOTA(\\d{3}).png" );
   const bfs::path path(".");
   find(path, defaultFilter);
}
```

The result is:

> found : 123 = .\X_ab_LOTA123.png

However if I rename the file to:

> X_a_LOTA123.png

i.e. I remove 'b' letter, and I also change the filter accordingly to:

```
const boost::regex defaultFilter( "X_a_LOTA(\\d{3}).png" );
```

then the program crashes!

I get bad_cast exception!

What am I doing wrong here? The code is simple. But it works only for some cases, for other names and matching patterns it crashes.

Please help.

Comment: What was your original regex?  It doesn't look like you changed it...

Comment: This might not be directly relevant for the question but the `.` character within your regex will not only match against a `.` in the path

Comment: Sorry, lost it during editing. Corrected the snippet now. There was "ab" in the working example.

Comment: Note: a plain dot in a regex matches any character except newline, it should be escaped with slash. I think that it's your regex which is at fault. Simply use a debugger or add a cout *before* the lexical cast to see what's going on.

Comment: The dot is certainly NOT a problem here. I made an experiment, renamed the file to "X_a_LOTA123" (without ".png"), and changed the pattern to "X_a_LOTA(\\d{3})", so there is no dot anywhere, and the problem still exists. I know that the problem is in the pattern, but I don't know where. The pattern is simple and I follow the rules of creating patterns. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour there. Your range-filter has side-effects, but the side-effect may have been overwritten by another range-entry before you inspect the results.

Therefore you are using `result[1]` when it may not be valid (there was a mismatch) or it might even refer to another path. Worse still, in this case the `path const&` reference taken by the second filter expression has become stale (it was derived from the `entry` loop variable at the time!).

Worst of all: your code was doomed once you wrote `path.filename().string()`, because it returns a temporary, and it gets destroyed at the end of the enclosing full-expression.

> *Running your code with debug-iterators or with address sanitizers would likely have alerted you about these problems*

Just simplify:

```
void find(const bfs::path& imageDirPath, const boost::regex& filter)
{
   for (auto entry : bfs::directory_iterator(imageDirPath)) {
       if (!is_regular_file(entry))
           continue;
       auto fname = entry.path().filename().string(); // keep alive longer than result!
       boost::smatch result;

       if (boost::regex_match(fname, result, filter)) {
           int32_t num = boost::lexical_cast<int32_t>(result[1]);
           cout << "found : " << num << " = " << entry.path().string() << endl;
       }
   }
}
```

In fact, you might add checks that the match group `[1]` is valid and was successfully matched before using it, since your function doesn't control the regular expression used.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem. I actually copied the code using boost::range::adaptors from one of the stackoverflow problems, I thought it would work. Thanks. You saved me a lot of time and explained the problem very well. I appreciate this :-)